# How did I Am Legend predict a "Superman vs Batman" movie?

Tags: i-am-legend

I remember that when watching I Am Legend a while ago, I noticed an advert for Batman vs Superman on a billboard (in the film itself).

I think this was when Batman Begins had recently come out. At the time it made me think there was a reason they'd put that in. It just made me wonder whether they had some insider information that this film was being planned, or if it was just a very good guess (although out by a couple years).

Comment: Nice catch, I've never been interested in re-watching that film until now.  I had preferred the Heston version, or even the Price version, to the Smith's.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"[I Am Legend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Legend_%28film%29)" was produced in 2007 but Warner Brothers had already heavily trailed the possibility of a Batman/Superman crossover film [as early as 2004](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2002/07/09/batman-vs-superman-in-04), going as far as confirming a Director and Head of Studio (neither of whom ultimately ended up working on the project).

The logo used in both "I Am Legend" and the upcoming "[Batman Vs Superman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/)" film is a variant of the Superman/Batman logo used in the [crossover comic of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman) back in **2003**.

It's also worth mentioning that the Producer of I Am Legend (Akiva Goldsman) was also involved in rewriting an aborted Superman/Batman film screenplay as far back as **2002**. You can read the failed screenplay [here](http://io9.com/read-the-screenplay-for-the-scrapped-2002-batman-vs-su-1218064972/all). Putting the logo in the film may have been a subtle jibe at Warner Bros.

**2003**
[image]

**2007**
[image]

**2014**
[image]

UPDATE:

Director Francis Lawrence has confirm this info in a recent interview with [Collider](http://collider.com/francis-lawrence-hunger-games-mockingjay-part-1-interview/). It was indeed down to Akiva Goldsman that the logo was chosen (hat tip to @collinvanuden) for the link.

Comment: TBH, Hollywood has been trying to get a Batman/Superman movie out for decades. If nothing else, it was a good guess at something that was bound to happen eventually.

Comment: @Omegacron - Not least because there's been huge numbers of canon crossovers between Superman and Batman in the comics and animated shows.

Answer (score 2):

I am Legend is a Warner Bros movie.  There are multiple easter-eggs in the movie pointing to "future" WB movies.  You have that Superman/Batman sign (the Superman logo in that one is the one used in Superman Returns with Brandon Roth), there's also a Green Lantern movie poster in the video store as well as a Teen Titans movie poster.

WB owns DC comics so them putting in those little bits was a mix of fun and a way to get fans talking at a time when all of those projects were in development.  Superman/Batman was ultimately scrapped due to the critical failure of Superman Returns, Green Lantern happened and I don't know the fate of the Teen Titans movie.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it was there is that the producer and writer of I Am Legend, Akiva Goldsman, actually wrote an early draft of a Batman and Superman movie.

> Lawrence and Goldsman decided to include the Batman and Superman logo
>   as a fun idea of what movies would have been released when the plagued
>   hit. Lawrence also revealed that when he recently ran into Goldsman
>   that he told him that they never even got permission from Warner Bros.
>   to include the Batman and Superman logo. However, since I Am Legend
>   was a Warner Bros. movie they really couldn’t sue themselves.'

Source: http://comicbook.com/2014/11/21/story-behind-batman-vs-superman-easter-egg-in-i-am-legend-reveal/

Comment: "They couldn't really sue themselves". [You'd think that](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/04/10/bank-of-america-foreclosure-suit_n_1415614.html), wouldn't you?

Comment: Please ensure you use block quotes when copying text, otherwise it looks like you're trying to pass someone else's writing off as your own.